# Mysql Email search with boolean giving bad values

Tags: php, mysql

i have problem with my search query. I'm searching for emails.

I have my search query like this:

```
  $query = sprintf("SELECT mailer_subscribers.id, mailer_subscribers.email, mailer_subscribers.status,mailer_segmentlinker.segment_id, mailer_segmenten.segmentnaam FROM mailer_subscribers 
                        JOIN mailer_segmentlinker ON mailer_subscribers.id=mailer_segmentlinker.subscriber_id
                        JOIN mailer_segmenten ON mailer_segmentlinker.segment_id=mailer_segmenten.id
                        WHERE MATCH (email) AGAINST ('%s*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)", $key);
```

But when i am typing a keyword in example "`john.smith`", it returns me all values that has the same name or surname

```
john.smith@example.com
john.notsmith@example.com
smith.hendrix@example.com
josh.josh@smith.com
```

i need that it will give me just list with `john.smith` .

---

Edit:

Solution which helped me was this:
 `WHERE mailer_subscribers.email LIKE '%%%s%%'", $key);`

Comment: try `WHERE email LIKE %john.smith%`

Answer (score 1):

Try to put your keyword in double quotes to search for the exact phrase.

```
... AGAINST ('\"%s*\"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ...
```

**[Boolean Full-Text Searches](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//fulltext-boolean.html):**

> 'apple banana'
>   Find rows that contain at least one of the two words.
>
> '"some words"'
>   Find rows that contain the exact phrase “some words”
>   (for example, rows that contain “some words of wisdom” but not “some
>   noise words”).

Comment: Thanks for the answers but, the solution is this:

` WHERE mailer_subscribers.email LIKE '%%%s%%'", $key);`